# AJAX:How to refresh JS when only div is refreshed using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onload

I am using below code to refresh only one DIV in the html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.active').live('click', function(event) {
        var elem = $(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(result) {
                var dtr = $("#test", result);
                $('#test').html(dtr);}
        });
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

But it is not loading the other JS like below code which I wrote in the same html page and worked when page is loaded or refreshing.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sScrollY": 200,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "sScrollXInner": "110%",
                "sSwfPath": "../mymedia/savefiles/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            }
        } )
        .columnFilter({
            aoColumns: {{columnfilters|safe}}
        });
    } );
</script>
```

Suggest me how can I call or refresh the JS automatically when the DIV is loaded or refreshed with AJAX.

Comment: You have to call again datatable right?

Comment: Yes, When DIV is refreshed I want to call datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Initially you initialized the table so first clear that table

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy();
```

Then initialize again after ajax success

```
$('#example').dataTable();
```

Like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('.active').live('click', function(event) {
$('#example').dataTable().fnDestroy(); 
var elem = $(this); 
var url = $(this).attr('href'); alert(url); 
$.ajax({ 
url: url, 
success: function(result) 
{ 
var dtr = $("#test", result); 
$('#test').html(dtr);
$('#example').dataTable( {
                "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                "oTableTools": {
                    "sScrollY": 200,
                    "sScrollX": "100%",
                    "sScrollXInner": "110%",
                    "sSwfPath": "../mymedia/savefiles/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
                }
            } )
            .columnFilter({
        aoColumns: {{columnfilters|safe}}
    });
} 
});
event.preventDefault(); 
event.stopPropagation();
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwwww...!! Very Nice.. it is working for me Thank you so much Sridhar